# censored data estimation

Tags: likelihood, exponential-distribution, censoring

Suppose $X_1, \cdots ,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed random variables with
probability density function
$$f(x|θ) = θ\, \exp(−θx),\quad \text{ for } x ≥ 0\,.$$
Each variable is censored if it exceeds $C$, a known constant.

Then we have: then
$$Pr(X > C) = \exp(−θC)\,.$$

Do anybody know why $$Pr(X > C) = \exp(−θC)?$$

Comment: What's the cdf that corresponds to the density you gave ($f$)?

Comment: What would you get if you integrate the density from C to Infinity?   What does censoring mean in this context?  Are you setting each value greater than C to C or are you discarding every X$_i$ that is greater than C in the sample?

Comment: @Michael Setting each value greater than C to C is winsorizing; discarding them is truncation -- and neither is strictly censoring, which would involve recording in some way that "$X>C$". However exactly what is done with the censored values doesn't relate to answering the question which is only about the probability that the value $C$ is exceeded in the first place.

Comment: @Glen_b The question as currently edited does appear to only address $Pr(X>C)$.  But I still am not sure what the OP had in mind by censoring.  Originally I thought the calculation was intended to determine what the distribution is after it is modified.

Comment: You can read the edit history as easily as I can and see every version that was posted including the [first one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/280112/10). The question has not been changed in any substantive way since the first version; it asked what it now asks.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x|θ) = θ e^{−θx}$ then $F(x|θ) = 1- e^{−θx}$ (by integration).

Hence $P(X>C) = 1-P(X\leq C) = 1-F(C) = 1-(1-e^{-\theta C}) = e^{-\theta C}$.